# how to send file to server with retrofit2 and alertDialog

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, retrofit2

hi i want send file to server with retrofit2 and alertDialog but i have somthing error .

my Request by retrofit2

```
@Multipart
    @POST("ads")
    Call<ResponseBody> getUpload(@Header("Authorization") String token
            , @Part("title") RequestBody title
            , @Part("description") RequestBody description
            , @Part("price") RequestBody price
            , @Part("tell") RequestBody tell
            , @Part("address") RequestBody address
            , @Part("category") RequestBody category
            , @Part MultipartBody.Part image);
```

i create one floatingAction Button for add item

```
FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showList();
            }
        });
```

i create onActivityResult For me when I choose to notify me by changing the name of the Button

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            saveUri = data.getData();
            btn_select.setText("Image Selected !");
        }
    }
```

i create showlist for show me layout add new post and me fill information with alertDialog

```
 private void showList() {
        Log.d(TAG, "showList: started");
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Home.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Add new post");
        alertDialog.setMessage("please fill all information");

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_new_post, null);

        tv_title = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        tv_category = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_category);
        tv_tell = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_tell);
        tv_price = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_price);
        tv_description = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
        tv_address = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_address);

        btn_select = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_select);
        btn_upload = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_upload);

        btn_select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                chooseImage();
            }
        });

        btn_upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                uploadImage(saveUri);
            }
        });


        alertDialog.setView(view);

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();

    }
```

i create chooseImage for select image for read image in my gallery.

```
private void chooseImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY_REQUEST);
    }
```

In the end i create uploadImage for send file to server

```
private void uploadImage(Uri uri) {
        Log.d(TAG, "uploadImage: started");

        tv_title = findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        tv_address = findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
        tv_description = findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
        tv_price = findViewById(R.id.tv_price);
        tv_tell = findViewById(R.id.tv_tell);
        tv_category = findViewById(R.id.tv_category);

        File originalFile = new File(uri.toString());

        RequestBody titlePart = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, tv_title.getText().toString());
        RequestBody addressPart = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, tv_address.getText().toString());
        RequestBody descriptionPart = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, tv_description.getText().toString());
        RequestBody pricePart = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, tv_price.getText().toString());
        RequestBody tellPart = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, tv_tell.getText().toString());
        RequestBody categoryPart = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, tv_category.getText().toString());

        RequestBody imagePart  = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(getContentResolver().getType(uri)),
                FileUtils.getFile(originalFile));

        MultipartBody.Part file = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", originalFile.getName(), imagePart);

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Get_Token", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String token = preferences.getString("Token", null);

        Call<ResponseBody> call = RetrofitClient.getmInstance().getApi().getUpload(token, titlePart, descriptionPart, pricePart, tellPart, addressPart, categoryPart, file);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

and show me this error

```
2019-05-29 12:12:46.647 19215-19215/com.example.book E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.book, PID: 19215
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.book.Activities.Home.uploadImage(Home.java:160)
        at com.example.book.Activities.Home.access$200(Home.java:53)
        at com.example.book.Activities.Home$3.onClick(Home.java:123)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11163)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23748)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

Now tell me where I got it wrong . thanks

Comment: can you please show your error log?

Comment: @MiteshMachhoya sry . i edit file and write error

Comment: check ur xml page clearly

Comment: ur declaration ids check main clas

Comment: @sureshmadaparthi changed my erro after to fix edittext

Comment: @Zoe Hi, I've fixed the problem and the program will not get any errors, but the file will not be sent to the server

Answer (score 1):

> Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a
>   subclass of which it is not an instance. For example, the following
>   code generates a ClassCastException:

**Error:-**

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.EditText

This error telling you that you are trying to typecast AppCompatTextView into EditText.

Go through your XML and check which one you are trying to cast forcefully.

Solution:- Change in your XML (TextView into EditaText) or in your activity (EditText into TextView).

Error:-

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null
>   object reference

NullPointerException telling you that the EditText object are you accessing is null. Because you didn't provide EditText object any memory. Means you are accessing it without binding.

Solution:- Bind your EditText object using findViewById to the id you have mentioned in XML.

Comment: change my erro after to fix edittext

Comment: Check answer and understand every Exception error. It will help you for long run.